# A given vector is not an unimodular scalar multiple of other

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $x,y$ be two distinct vectors in $X$ with the following property:

$(1)$ $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$.

$(2)$ $x\neq \mu y$ for any unimodular scalar $\mu$.

From this can we assume that $x-\alpha y\neq \theta$ for any scalar $\alpha$, where $\theta$ denotes the zero vector in $X$?

My reasoning:

Suppose on the contrary that $x-\alpha y= \theta$ for some $\alpha$, then we have that $\|x\|=|\alpha|\|y\|$. Since $x$ and $y$ are unit vectors, we must have $|\alpha|=1$. Therefore, $x=\alpha y$ for some unimodular scalar $\alpha$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $x-\alpha y\neq \theta$ for any scalar $\alpha$, as expected.

Comment: yes, it’s fine.

Comment: Thank you @YanPeng